# Why does Python take so long to process my Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm making a Python program that matches all the emails in a string and returns them to the user:

```
emailRegex = re.compile(r'((.*)+@(.*)+\.(.*){3})')
text = "John Smith, Vice Provost for Undergraduate Studies\n123-456-7890\njohn.smith@email.edu"
emailList = emailRegex.findall(text)
clipOut = []
for tup in emailList:
     clipOut.append(tup[0])
print(clipOut)
```

I ran this program for over 9 minutes without any output

Strangely enough, changing the text string to `"John\n123-456-7890\njohn.smith@email.edu"` causes the Regex to match nearly instantly.

Adding more text to the first line in the text string makes the Regex take increasingly longer to match. The string `John Smith, Vice Provost\n123-456-7890\njohn.smith@email.edu` takes just over 10 seconds to run on my laptop. Reducing the amount of characters before the email increases matching speed. Changing the characters used does not increase matching speed. However, removing all new lines makes the program run at expected speeds, regardless of the amount of characters before email.

Finally, changing the regex to:

`emailRegex = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))')`

Makes the program run just fine, regardless of string length.

I understand that my Regex was flawed, but I don't understand why it causes my program to take so long to run

Comment: Why do you have `+` after `(.*)`? It doesn't change anything and is probably causing catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: `(.*){3}` also doesn't make sense. The first repetition will match the rest of the string, and the other 2 repetitions will match nothing.

Comment: See [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error was presumably caused by the `+` after `(.*)`. Changing the regex to `emailRegex = re.compile(r'((.+)@(.+)\.(.){2,4})')` causes the program to run as expected. Thank you for the help!